# install AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle

Tags: symfony

I am trying to install AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle in the last version of symfony but I have had several problem

first I tried to use composer but  I obtain this error

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package cedriclombardot/admingenerator-generator-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package knplabs/knp-menu-bundle master could not be found.
```

Finally I used git to install all vendor

The installation of this vendor is to extensive, so before to Install TwigGenerator a have to execute

```
php app/console admin:setup
```

but I obtain this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::registerNamespaces() in
```

the line 14 in autoLoad file contain this..

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Admingenerator'    => array(__DIR__.'/../src', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles'),
    'Sensio\Bundle'     => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'Knp\Bundle' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'Knp\Menu'   => __DIR__.'/../vendor/KnpMenu/src',
));
```

any idea!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem, but instead of manually installing with git, I changed `minimum-stability` flag to `dev` in `composer.json`:

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
```

And added these deps:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master",
    "cedriclombardot/admingenerator-generator-bundle": "dev-master"
```

Comment: thanks @thecatontheflat but I still have the same problem, when I execute  php app/console admin:setup I obtain this error, 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::registerNamespaces() any idea!